# How can I get a random x and y coordinate inside a circle radius?

Tags: php, math

I figured I'd use rand() to get a number between 0 and 20000 twice to get a random x and y coordinate. This works but it gives me random coordinates from within a square.

What I really need is coordinates within a circle. How can I limit my random x/y to within a circle which has a radius of 20,000?

I've tried a few sample codes online but most of those seem to be for computing spheres and finding the distance between two points on a sphere and I'm not knowledgeable enough to apply those to my usage of just picking a random coordinate within a circle (flat) radius.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you assuming a circle of radius 10000 with a center at (10000,10000)? 20000 radius doesn't make sense with the rest of the limitations unless you only sample from the first quarter.

Comment: Yep. -20,000 to 20,000 with the centre of the circle being 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random coordinates around a location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620550/generate-random-coordinates-around-a-location)

Comment: Any point (x,y) is contained in a circle of radius r with center (0,0) if the Euclidean distance (0,0) and (x,y) is less  than r ( d = sqrt(x^2 + y^2) ). Could sample for (x,y) and try again until you hit one that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a random `x` between -20,000 and 20,000 and use Pythagoras law to get the positive `y` value. Then you do a random 0 or 1 to make that value positive or negative.

An example:

```
$r = 20000;
$x = rand(-$r, $r);
$y = rand(0, 1) ? -sqrt(pow($r, 2) - pow($x, 2)) : sqrt(pow($r, 2) - pow($x, 2));
var_dump($x, $y);
```

I am not sure how the numbers are distributed exactly but it sounds about right.

**Edit:** Thanks @andand, of course this calculates points on the circle only. To get points anywhere in the circle, the calculated `y` value is the maximum:

```
$r = 20000;
$x = rand(-$r, $r);
$yMax = sqrt(pow($r, 2) - pow($x, 2));
$y = rand(-$yMax, $yMax);
var_dump($x, $y);
```

Comment: I don't see how any of the points generated will be interior to the circle.  They appear to all be on the perimeter and not uniformly distributed even there.

Comment: @andand You are of course completely right. Like I mentioned in my original answer, I am not sure about the distribution but it should be okay, apart from strange behaviour of `rand()` I can't think of any reason why it should not be uniform. Perhaps some maths I am not seeing...

Comment: The update has points clustered in the Y direction non-uniformly at the extreme X values and tends to become more sparse closer to X=0.  This is because while rand() is uniform, the area of the region associated with a given interval of X values is not constant across the possible range of X values.  This tends to compress the Y values at the extremes and spread them out more in the central regions.

Comment: @andand Makes sense, better to use a random distance with a random angle then. I'd better upvote the better solutions then :-)

Answer (score 3):

To generate uniform distributed random points inside the circle of radius R, you can use the [next approach](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html):

```
a = Random  //range 0..1
b = Random  
theta = b * 2 * Pi
rr = R * Sqrt(a)
x = rr * Cos(theta)
y = rr * Sin(theta)
```

Comment: @andand You probably missed `sqrt` for radial part. It provides uniformity. I've added link to mathworld page.

Comment: Yes, I missed it... skipped right over it in my blind rush to judgment in fact.

Answer (score 2):

## Generalised function to return a random point within a circle:

```
/**
 * @param $radius integer
 * @return array['x', 'y']
 */
function getPoint($radius)
{
    $i = mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax();
    $j = mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax();

    $w = $radius * sqrt($i);
    $theta = (2 * pi() * $j);
    $x = $radius + ($w * cos($theta));
    $y = $radius + ($w * sin($theta));

    return compact('x', 'y');
}
```

## Bonus implementation in GD:

```
$radius = 250;

$image = imagecreatetruecolor((2 * $radius) + 1, (2 * $radius) + 1);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0,   0,   0);

imagefill($image, 0, 0, $white);
imageellipse($image, $radius, $radius, $radius * 2, $radius * 2, $black);

for ($a = 0; $a < 1000; $a++)
{
    $point = getPoint($radius);
    imagesetpixel($image, $point['x'], $point['y'], $black);
}

// Output the image.
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
```